A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core' and firebase_auth'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.


Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-2.27.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

In most cases it's a cache problem. It could be pub cache, build cache or gradle cache. Even though, the error message points to the pub cache, this exact error was solved for me by removed gradle cache folder. But just in case, some useful commands for issues like that.
This will clean pub cache:
flutter pub cache clean

This will clean flutter build cache and redownload dependencies.
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Other cases for issues like that, are incompatible library versions. You should make sure that gradle plugin version is compatible with android jdk version and your flutter dependencies compatible with you flutter version, and your platform plugins compatible with java/kotlin/swift/.. versions.
It sounds scary, but these tips will help you to solve 90% of flutter build issues.
